# Is this an ordinay function, a constructor or neither?

Tags: javascript, class, object, constructor, jsdoc

I use to enjoy using js. Now I am just frustrated. I am trying to jsDoc a large chunk of code that was purchased by my boss. The author did not provide an API so I am going to create one using jsDoc.

Unfortunately the code is not clear and it contains about 10k lines of code in one js file. I have used object literals in the past, this is not an object literal. The parameters and functions are not separated by commas. Additionally, a prototype is never used, but the new operator is. I have looked in several books and namespacing appears to be the closest 'style'. Here is the generic flow of the program. My questions follow the example.

```
(function () {
var global = (function () {return this; } ).call();
global.X = {};
})();

X.init = function(){
    X.MyObjectA = new X.FooA();
    X.MyObjectB = new X.FooB();
}

X.FooA = function() {
   var storeStuff;
   do stuff
   .
   .
   function bar(){
        var storeSomething;
        do something
        do somthing else
        .
        .
        moreFunctions(){}
        var moreVars;
        .
        .

    }

    this.anOccasionalFunctionLiteral = function(){}
        .
        .
}

X.FooB = function(){
    Similar contents of FooB()
 }
 .
 .
 .
 Continues forever...
```

So my questions are:

1. What *style* is this!? When I say style I guess I really mean what are FooA and FooB? Are they objects? Classes?
2. What title should I give the nested functions **if they aren't members of X.FooA or X.FooB**. I have been told nested functions, including bar(), are not methods of *objects* FooA and FooB.
3. If the function nested inside of the *object* is in fact not a method of its surrounding object can it be called from anywhere? Or do normal scope rules apply?

To make life more readable and happy I have been classifying *objects* similar to FooA and FooB as constructors and any methods inside of the constructors, such as bar(), as methods of FooA and FooB. This may not be correct but at least it's organized. Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FooA and FooB are constructor functions.

The nested functions are "private" functions.

The bar function inside of FooA can only be called inside FooA.

See 
http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Answer (score 1):

1) I think your namespacing hunch was correct. The first self-executing anonymous function gets the global namespace. They probably didn't do something simple like:

```
window.X = {};
```

because that won't work in environments where 'window' isn't the global object. (like nodejs on the server)

2) I wouldn't call these methods. Personally, I think it depends on what the actual functionality of those functions is. They could be acting like further namespaces or constructors for objects. If they are capitalized the author was probably thinking of them more as namespaces or classes, rather than methods.

3) The bar() function can only be called from X.FooA, be aware however, that it can be called within X.FooA **before** it is actually declared

```
X.FooA = function() {
  bar(); // this will work
  function bar() {
    alert('this will work');
  }
}
```

This is because the function declaration will be hoisted to the top of the surrounding function when the code is evaluated. The bar function will not be available outside of X.FooA however.

I don't think I would classify bar as a method. Perhaps as a 'private function' or 'private method' would be more apt.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like FooA and FooB are classes contained within the 'X' object. The anonymous functions within the defined classes are essentially private methods, whereas the named one is a public method of the containing class.

```
var x = {
 classA:function(){
  do class constructor stuff...
  function myPrivateMethod(){do stuff...}
  this.myPublicMethod = function(){do stuff...}
 },
 classB:{another class contained in the object}
}
```